# Table does not load data while reading file shows empty table

Tags: python, list, qt, pyqt5

I am trying to convert a markdown file to GUI table, so I tried to change the markdown file to a nested list and then change the list to a table, but i found myself between two errors: list out of range if i try to delete some sublist from the nested list, or it works but shows an empty table.

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import datetime
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    import datetime
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 311, 301))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 430, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
**hears what i tried**
        Data = self.convertolist()

        numrows = len(Data)  # number of rows in your example
        numcols = len(Data[0])  # number of columns in your example

        # Set colums and rows in QTableWidget
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numcols)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numrows)

        # Loops to add values into QTableWidget
        for row in range(numrows):
            for column in range(numcols):
                 
                
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem((Data[row][column])))



        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        #item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        #item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "From"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
       # item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "To"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load"))
        
        

    

   
    def convertolist(self):

        with open("list.md", "r") as f:

            
                text=f.readlines()
                data=[]
                for l in text:
                    
                    line=list()
                    
                    
                    line=l.split('|')
                    line.pop()
                    data.append(line)
                    #data = [i for i in data if i and (i[2] != 'v0.1.0')]#if i try this out of range err appears
                print(data)

                return(data)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the convertolist function convert my md file to nested list

```
| Item | v0.1.0 | v0.2.0 | v0.3.0 | v0.3.1 | v0.9.0 | v1.0.0 | v1.1.0 | v1.1.1 | v1.2.0 | v1.3.0|v1.3.1|v1.3.2|v1.3.3|v1.3.4
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
| **Requirements** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| [&#129501;] All Pull Requests completed or ignored                      | :white_check_mark:    | :white_check_mark:   | :white_check_mark:   |:white_check_mark:   |:white_check_mark:   | :white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark: | :white_check_mark: | :white_check_mark: | :white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark: | :white_check_mark:
| [&#129501;] Project documentation is up-to-date <details>README.md, RELEASE-NOTES.md and and Doxygen generated</details> | :white_large_square:  | :white_check_mark:   | :white_check_mark:   |:white_check_mark:     |:white_check_mark:   | :white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark: | :white_check_mark: | :white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark:     | :white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark: |:white_check_mark:
| [&#129501;] Built and samples execution done with success |  :white_large_square: | :white_large_square: | :white_large_square: |:white_check_mark:     |:white_check_mark:     | :white_check_mark:     |:white_check_mark:     |:white_check_mark: | :white_check_mark:| :white_check_mark:| :white_check_mark:| :white_check_mark:|:white_check_mark:|:white_check_mark:
|
```

Comment: You're setting the column count = 3, two times. Can you try this without doing so?

`self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)`
`self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numcols)`

Also, try once after commenting out this: `self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)`

Comment: i tried what you told me but the table is still empty am gonna add my md file so you can better understand me .thanks any way @AmanSachdeva

Comment: When you `print(data)`, do you see your data?

Comment: yes it shows a nested list [['', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'], ['', ' **Requirements** ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']] this is the first two ligne @TimRoberts

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that all the lines have the same number of fields?  Perhaps you should check that.  I'll add an answer below with a suggestion.

Comment: @Eline please don't add code in comments as it doesn't support formatting and makes it completely unreadable. [edit] your post and add further information there, also check that you're properly [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and verify that it's properly displayed in the post preview.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that there's a blank line, or some other line that has a different number of fields.  I suggest you do this:

```
        # Loops to add values into QTableWidget
        for nrow, row in enumerate(Data):
            for ncol, field in enumerate(row):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(nrow, ncol, QTableWidgetItem(field))
```

This would still crash if any line had fewer fields than your header row, since that's what you use to establish the table widget.